# Split multiple Strings in java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and trying to split multiple strings and store it in a String array. The layman program follows:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1 = "Hello1 Hello2";
    String s2 = "Hello3 Hello4";
    String s3 = "Hello5 Hello6";
    String[] parts = s1.split(" ");
    parts = s2.split(" "); //Rewrites
    parts = s3.split(" "); //Rewrites
    for(String s4:parts) { 
      System.out.print(s4 + " ");
    }
```

The ouput of the program is obviously : Hello5 Hello6. ([How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java))

Regardless I expect the output Hello1 Hello2 Hello3 Hello4 Hello5 Hello6. Which is, the incoming string must not replace the existing Strings inside the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays are fixed-length, so all you can do is replace their existing elements, or create a new, separate array.

It is easier if you use a `List`, which can be variable-length, and use `addAll` to add the results of the `split` to that:

```
List<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();
parts.addAll(Arrays.asList(s1.split(" ")));
parts.addAll(Arrays.asList(s2.split(" ")));
parts.addAll(Arrays.asList(s3.split(" ")));
```

Note that you have to use `Arrays.asList` here because `split` returns a `String[]`, whereas `addAll` requires a collection of `String`, e.g. `List<String>`.